# How to query specific item in json array return from mongodb using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a json result return from mongodb  each element has array onside it 
I would like to query the array element to find a specific node ,
without using the id or email as filter **only the token number as a filter (its a unique number)**

```
this is how one of the items json   looks like 
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5cf67ad97739bfe8525e5353"),
"Email" : "eyal@gmail.com",
"Username" : "eyal",
"Password" : "1234",
"Tokens" : [ 
    {
        "Tokennumber" : "123",
        "Valid" : "true",
        "LoginDate" : ISODate("2019-06-04T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "Tokennumber" : "124",
        "Valid" : "false",
        "LoginDate" : ISODate("2019-06-04T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "Tokennumber" : "555",
        "Valid" : true,
        "LoginDate" : ISODate("2019-06-07T08:32:01.854Z")
    }

]
}
I would like to query the json using only one parameter  Tokennumber=555
```

the token number is a unique number  so i need to fetch the whole node by querying it by his Tokennumber

```
 the expected result would be the node 
 with this 
 data

"_id" : ObjectId("5cf67ad97739bfe8525e5353"),
"Email" : "eyal@gmail.com",
"Username" : "eyal",
"Password" : "1234",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following mongo query get's the job done using $elemMatch

```java
db.User.aggregate({
    "$match": {
        "Tokens": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "TokenNumber": "234"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

here's the c# code that generated the above aggregation pipeline. it's using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) which is just a wrapper for the official driver. [disclaimer: i'm the author]

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class User : Entity
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public Token[] Tokens { get; set; }
        }

        public class Token
        {
            public string TokenNumber { get; set; }
            public bool Valid { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            (new User
            {
                Email = "email@domain.com",
                Tokens = new[] {
                    new Token{ TokenNumber="123",Valid = false },
                    new Token{ TokenNumber="234",Valid = true },
                    new Token{ TokenNumber="456",Valid = false },
                }
            }).Save();

            var user = DB.Queryable<User>()
                         .Where(u => u.Tokens.Any(t => t.TokenNumber == "234"))
                         .Single();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
since you mentioned you are unable to use the library, the following would be how to do it with the official driver:

```cs
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter
                           .ElemMatch(u => u.Tokens, 
                                      t => t.TokenNumber == "234");

var user = collection.Find(filter)
                     .Single();
```

```cs
var user = collection.Aggregate()
                     .Match(u => u.Tokens.Any(t => t.TokenNumber == "234"))
                     .ToList()
                     .Single();
```

```cs
var user = collection.AsQueryable()
                     .Where(u => u.Tokens.Any(t => t.TokenNumber == "234"))
                     .Single();
```

Comment: hey ryan appreciate you answer  but i couldnt install  it via nuget  i got this error "Could not install package 'MongoDB.Entities 6.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"

Comment: @eyalberda sorry the library only supports .net core + asp .net core projects. if you are tied to the full framework then i'm afraid you'd be out of luck.

Comment: @eyalberda i updated my answer above with 3 methods of doing it with the official driver.

Answer (score 0):

**You can access nodes types using filter.**

> e.g:

```
var filter = Builders<YourObject>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Tokens.Any(t => t.Tokennumber == tokerNume), true);

var result = MongoContext.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<YourObject>("YourDocument").Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thaks for your reply but it doesnt work i get "Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.tokens.Any(t => (t.tokennumber == value(RETDATAAPI.Classes.Checkuserauthentication+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).decryptedtoken))."