# FilterDefinition<MyObject> - How to query object in array?

Tags: c#, mongodb

i have a list below, i don't know how to query object in array

```
class a
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public List<b> Attr{get;set;}
}

class b
{
   public string Card{get;set;}
   public sring SN{get;set;}
}
```

C# how to write a query ? use FilterDefinition

```
FilterDefinition<a> filter = Builders<a>.Filter.Empty;
a.Eq( q=>q.Attr.Card, '001') ..., wrong...
```

Comment: [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507328/4368485) shows 4 different methods of querying nested documents in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [ElemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). You can then pass a filter for the array items as either a `FilterDefinition<b>` or a lambda expression:

```
FilterDefinition<a> filter = Builders<a>.Filter.ElemMatch(q => q.Attr, Builders<b>.Filter.Eq(attr => attr.Card, "001"));
```

or

```
FilterDefinition<a> filter = Builders<a>.Filter.ElemMatch(q => q.Attr, attr => attr.Card == "001");
```

Comment: please help this also , thank you .     https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385952/c-mongodb-filterdefinitiont-multiple-level-array-object-query-how-to-do

Comment: @badcodeforme You posted that on the _meta_ StackOverflow site (i.e. a site intended for discussions about _this site_, not for programming questions). Anyway, you see how I did the ElemMatch's subquery here, it looks like you'll need another subquery for the subquery. Note that unless it's indexed, that won't be very efficient.